# How to use MySQLparameter array in Mysqlcommand to add with command

Tags: mysql, arrays, .net, command, mysql-parameter

I have a mysqlcommand and mysqlparameter array []

```
  MySqlParameter[] param = new MySqlParameter[]{
      // params here
    };
```

Now I want to set the command parameter for this array. How I can do that? I got the error:

**MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:**

> Only MySqlParameter objects may be
> stored

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a parameters array directly to the SqlCommand.Parameters property, you need to use the AddRange method or add parameters one by one

```
mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddRange(param);
```

OR

```
for (int count = 0; count < param.Length; count++)
{
    mysqlcommand.Parameters.Add(param[count]);
}
```